# JHipster - Problems with the configuration of LDAPS

Tags: ldap, jhipster

I've genrated my application with JHipster. I've changed the authentication way in my project to use **LDAPS**.

I added configuration in application.yml

Server SSL:

```
 key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
 key-store-password: secret
 key-password: secret
```

I didn't add any other code (i.e. java) for this certificate.

When I try to launch my application in a browser, it doesn't work; however if I delete this configuration, it works. Does my application really needs a certificate for the connection to **LDAPS**?

What is wrong with this code, should I add java code somewhere to complete my configuration?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to help you. Which version of JHipster, which authentication did you choose when generating your app?

To make it work with LDAP you must change the SecurityConfiguration class.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. It was a problem in my configuration file. I fixed it.